# Como formatar uma data em CDT?

Tags: php, data

Como faço para uma data nesse formato `Tue, 3 May 2016 12:49:24 -0500` (CDT) ficar assim `03/05/2016`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui achar uma solução:

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime('Tue, 3 May 2016 12:49:24 -0500 (CDT)'));
```